# Multithreaded application fails to compile with error-chain

Tags: multithreading, rust

I introduced `error-chain` into a previously working application. The error itself is clear, `std::error::Error + 'static` lacks an implementation of the `trait std::marker::Send`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::error::Error + 'static: std::marker::Send` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:35:5
   |
35 | /     error_chain!{
36 | |
37 | |         foreign_links {
38 | |             Mqttc(::mqttc::Error);
...  |
53 | |         }
54 | |     }
   | |_____^ `std::error::Error + 'static` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::error::Error + 'static`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<std::error::Error + 'static>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<std::error::Error + 'static>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `mqttc::netopt::Error`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `mqttc::Error`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `errors::ErrorKind`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `errors::Error`
   = note: required by `error_chain::ChainedError`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. Note that I am using the more [up to date fork of `mqttc/mqtt3`](https://github.com/amikhalev/rust-mq) instead of the upstream crates.

Comment: You cannot share any object between threads. You must use a Mutex.

Comment: So essentially error-chain declares some static entities which I want to use in multpile threads. How do I handle this use case with error-chain?

Comment: I do not know this crate, but maybe you should ask in an github issue?

Comment: @Boiethios The OP is not trying to share an object between multiple threads, but (according to the error message) to **send** (move) an object between threads. `Send` supported by almost any object in Rust, with the exception of the few specifically blacklisted ones, such as `Rc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mqttc::Error` contains a `mqttc::netopt::Error`, which in turns contains a `Box<std::error::Error>` (which desugars to `std::boxed::Box<std::error::Error + 'static>`. `std::error::Error` here is a trait object. Because the `Error` trait doesn't have `Send` as a supertrait, implementations of `Error` are not required to implement `Send`. Therefore, `Box<std::error::Error>` doesn't implement `Send` because not all types `T: std::error::Error` implement `Send`.

This could be fixed by changing the `mqttc::netopt::Error` type to use `Box<std::error::Error + Send>` instead of `Box<std::error::Error>` (which would be a breaking change for the library).

Comment: Excellent explanation.